# Launch Stadia with hardware video acceleration

Tags: chromium, webapps

Although it's possible to play Stadia in Ubuntu directly with Google Chrome or Chromium, it's not possible to do it with automatic Hardware Video Acceleration.

- In Google Chrome, although it's possible to enable it through the `chrome://flags/` it's not really activated.
- In Chromium, the HW acceleration is not available in the normal repository

How can I execute it and create a shortcut (.desktop file) to run it as a WebApp?

Answer (score 0):

### Install Chromium Beta

1. Add the repository with HW acceleration

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:saiarcot895/chromium-beta
   sudo apt update
   ```
2. Install Chromium Beta

   ```
   sudo apt install chromium-browser
   ```
3. In Chromium write in the URL `chrome://flags/` --> enable "Hardware-accelerated video decode"

### Check HW video Acceleration

As we have said, although in `chrome://gpu/` appears `Video Decode: Hardware accelerated`, it doesn't mean it's really so.

Check it directly running a video with Chromium

1. Execute a 4K video in Youtube (to force the GPU to run)
2. Open `chrome://media-internals/`
3. In the **Players** Tab, press in the blue box with the Youtube Link and check if **kVideoDecoderName = "MojoVideoDecoder"** --> This is VP9 Codec
4. If there is anything else shown, like **"VpxVideoDecoder"** it means is not really enabled.

Note: Tested with Ubuntu 20.10 and Intel(R) UHD Graphics 630

### Create a WebApp shortcut

1. Create a file (i.e. google-stadia.desktop) with the following content:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
   [Desktop Entry]
   Version=1.0
   Terminal=false
   Type=Application
   Name=Stadia
   Exec=chromium-browser --app=https://stadia.google.com/home
   Icon=/home/$USERNAME/.local/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/apps/google-stadia.png
   ```
2. Download a Stadia Icon as .png (look for "stadia icon 256x256" in google) and copy it

   ```
   cp google-stadia.png /home/$USERNAME/.local/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/apps/google-stadia.png
   ```
3. Install the .desktop file (it copies it inside `~/.local/share/applications/` ) with:

   ```
   xdg-desktop-menu install google-stadia.desktop
   ```

Now it will be available directly from Ubuntu Dash, and you can put it in your dock.

---

To uninstall the .desktop file simply run:
`xdg-desktop-menu uninstall google-stadia.desktop`